# Where can I find more info on DFP tags and parameters

Tags: javascript, google-dfp, google-ima

This page  : https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/1068325?hl=en does not cover all available optional and required parameters.

More specifically I want to know what the following are used for :

- ged
- eid
- sdr

Answer (score 0):

The Google documentation does cover the ad-request parameters that the publisher (website) can append and that DFP will interpret and act on.

However, the video ad-request is made by the video player via the IMA SDK, which appends its own parameters, e.g. ged as discussed on the IMA SDK google group.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ima-sdk/D2kxzDg93bQ

I suppose that you and I cannot or should not use those parameters and therefore Google does not document them.

Having said that, the Google techies do seem willing to provide some information via the google group - which may be the best place to get more information if you feel you need it.

Answer (score 0):

These are parameters used for things like engagement tracking (ged=), which tracks whether the user is engaged with the page based on signals like scroll events, etc. They are added to the request by the player specific SDK (Flash, HTML5, etc).

These parameters are not included in the official documentation unfortunately, and are not found in the SDK docs.

https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1068325?hl=en